# Conditionally UPDATE a single row in one table if qualifying AVG value in another table

Tags: php, mysql

My coding attempt does not work as expected.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$query = " SELECT AVG(`humidity`) 
           FROM `ESP8622TEST` 
           WHERE `logdatetime` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR)";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        printf ("humidity: %s ", $row[0] );  
    }
      
    if ($row[0] <= '30'){
        $connect = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
        $querycase = "UPDATE PODLEWDLUGO 
                      SET podlewanieonoff='1' ,jakdlugo='8' 
                      WHERE id=1 ";
        mysqli_query($connect, $querycase);
    };
    if ($row[0] <= '35' && $row[0] >='30'){
        $connect = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx");
        $querycase = "UPDATE PODLEWDLUGO 
                      SET podlewanieonoff='1' ,jakdlugo='7'
                      WHERE id=1 ";
        mysqli_query($connect, $querycase);
    };
?>
```

It seems `$row[0]` is always `0` because it always UPDATEs the table with `8`, but printf works fine. Did I make a syntax/logic error? Should I use something other than `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: You try to access `$row` outside of the while-loop where it is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqli_fetch_row instead of mysqli_fetch_array in your while loop.
The documentation is here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Also, your if statements are outside the while loop. I think that $row[0] refers to the last row of your returned rows if not null.

Let me know if that solved your problem

Comment: i need to use it in while loop and it works dont need to switch to mysqli_fetch_array very mach thanks :D a

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your snippet is failing, but if this was a task in one of my applications, I would completely rewrite it to only make one trip to the database.

Code: ([db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qb7v887RGECyFxLdnR7AnR/6))

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "db");

$sql = <<<SQL
UPDATE subject AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(humidity) AS avg_humidity
    FROM ESP8622TEST
    WHERE logdatetime > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR)
) t ON avg_humidity <= 35
SET watering_onoff = 1,
    how_long = IF(avg_humidity <= 30, 8, 7)
WHERE s.id = 1
SQL;
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

If there were three humidity readings in the last two hours and they were:

- `30`, `30`, and `30` (avg = `30`), then the `watering_onoff` would be toggled to `1` and the `how_long` value would become `8`.
- `30`, `30`, and `45` (avg = `35`), then the `watering_onoff` would be toggled to `1` and the `how_long` value would become `7`.
- `30`, `30`, and `60` (avg = `40`), then the `watering_onoff` and the `how_long` values would remain unchanged.

The combination of the INNER JOIN (containing a subquery) and the WHERE clauses enforce the qualification of the single row (id = 1).